# Macos: admin user turns into a standard user account after restart

Tags: macos, mac, macos-mojave

I have a `MacOS Mojave` machine, where I'm creating a new user account with administrative privileges using the following command:

```
sudo sysadminctl -addUser 'userName' -password 'password' -admin
```

This works great and creates the user as an administrator. However, after rebooting the machine the created user turns into a standard user account. Why this might happen?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/macos-admin-user-turns-into-a-standard-user-account-after-restart

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8296997)

> If admin account name is changed and it is converted into standard
> account